# How can I replace html tags with components in React while still rendering the html tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string which contains HTML tags like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipisicing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
<strong>Duis</strong> aute irure dolor in <a 
href="https://example.com">Link to replace with React component</a>.</p>
<p>Next paragraph</p>
```

I want to replace all `<a>` tags with a React component and then render the string inside my render function. While still rendering the html tags such as `<p>`, `<strong>` and so forth. I've found this [How to replace parts of a string with a component?](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3386) which replaces the string but does not render the other html tags as it should. And I can't use dangerouslySetInnerHTML because I have an object (containing the React component) after replacing the string. The object I get after replacing the string and want to render:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
{
  "type": "span",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    "children": [
      "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipisicing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
<strong>Duis</strong> aute irure dolor in <a 
href="https://example.com">Link to replace with React component</a>.</p>",
  {
    "key": "1",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {},
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  },
  "</p>
  <p>Next paragraph</p>\n"
]
},
  "_owner": null,
  "_store": {}
}
```

How can I render both the html tags from before and the new components in the string?

Comment: This question is dead, but for anyone looking for an answer, you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react